# Automatic node placement without overlapping

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, diagrams

I am trying to generate an ER diagram with automatic positioning of the nodes. 
This code has got a nice output, but I have to manage manually the position of the nodes.
I have tried to replace "left of = person" but doing this way the nodes become overlapped.
How can I tell tikz to automatically position the nodes somewhere near "Person"?

```
\documentclass[a4paper ,11pt,x11names]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{er}

\tikzset{multi attribute/.style={attribute,double distance=1.5pt}} 
\tikzset{derived attribute/.style={attribute ,dashed}} 
\tikzset{total/.style={double distance=1.5pt}}
\tikzset{every entity/.style={draw=orange, fill=orange!20}}
\tikzset{every attribute/.style={draw=MediumPurple1, fill=MediumPurple1!20}} 
\tikzset{every relationship/.style={draw=Chartreuse2, fill=Chartreuse2!20}} 

\newcommand{\key}[1]{\underline{#1}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=7em]
        \node[entity] (person) {Person};
        \node[attribute] (pid) [left of = person] {\key{ID}} edge (person); 
        \node[attribute] (name) [above left of=person] {Name} edge (person); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Autoplacement is a quite nontrivial task that TikZ cannot do. You can find an alternative scheme of placement so that they don't overlap and then connect to `Person`

Answer (score 2):

This would not be entirely automatic in all cases, but the `positioning` library does a better job than the deprecated `left of`, `above left of` syntax. For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,multi,border=10pt,svgnames,dvipsnames,x11names]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{er,positioning}
\tikzset{%
  multi attribute/.style={attribute,double distance=1.5pt},
  derived attribute/.style={attribute ,dashed},
  total/.style={double distance=1.5pt},
  every entity/.style={draw=orange, fill=orange!20},
  every attribute/.style={draw=MediumPurple1, fill=MediumPurple1!20},
  every relationship/.style={draw=Chartreuse2, fill=Chartreuse2!20},
}
\newcommand{\key}[1]{\underline{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[entity] (person) {Person};
  \node[attribute] (pid) [left = of person] {\key{ID}} edge (person);
  \node[attribute] (name) [above left = of person] {Name} edge (person);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: positioning output]

Alternatively, if your diagram takes the form of a tree, `forest` can automatically layout the tree and position the nodes appropriately. For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,multi,border=10pt,svgnames,dvipsnames,x11names]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{er}
\tikzset{%
  multi attribute/.style={attribute,double distance=1.5pt},
  derived attribute/.style={attribute ,dashed},
  total/.style={double distance=1.5pt},
  every entity/.style={draw=orange, fill=orange!20},
  every attribute/.style={draw=MediumPurple1, fill=MediumPurple1!20},
  every relationship/.style={draw=Chartreuse2, fill=Chartreuse2!20},
}
\newcommand{\key}[1]{\underline{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={%
    grow'=180
  }
  [Person, name=person, entity
    [\key{ID}, name=pid, attribute, calign with current edge]
    [Name, name=name, attribute]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: Forest positioning]

Another option would be the `chains` library, for example. For truly automatic positioning, you might look at the Lua-based `graph` drawing algorithms offered by TikZ.